# How to hide header and footer or only header from last page in odoo qweb report (Odoo V11)?

Tags: xml, odoo, invoice, qweb, odoo-11

I need a help.

I want to remove both header and footer or only header from last page in qweb-report. Because I will put different information to last page. Header and footer mustn't become in last page. How can I do this ? Is it possible ?

```html
<t t-if="doc_model == 'stock.picking'">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <t t-foreach="range(0,2)" t-as="tt">
                 <div class="col-xs-6">
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-xs-5" style="padding-top:90px;">
                             <h4><strong>bla bla bla</strong></h4>
                             <p>bla bla bla</p>
                             <p>bla bla bla</p>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
                             <p>bla bla bla</p>
                             <p>bla bla bla</p>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
```

Comment: Please Clear the Question Who to use the Technique and language

Comment: I cleared important words from code. Thanks

Comment: One way is there you can check No of pages via putting page numbers and check if there is not any next page in your report then consider it as a last page and hide header/footer or replace it with your custom one.

Answer (score 0):

in order to achieve that all you have to is to not define a header or a footer in your table and use css to apply header style like to header as well as the footer. this will make your header and footer to not repeat among pages.